# Error with mysql-secure-installation - socket

Tags: mysql, dockerfile, mysql-8.0

I got an error trying to make mysql-secure-installation :
Error: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
The command '/bin/sh -c DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && mysql_secure_installation --user root --host localhost' returned a non-zero code: 1

I use the below dockerfile and build my image that way: sudo docker build -t hello .

```
FROM debian:buster
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y upgrade && apt-get -y dist-upgrade && apt-get install -y nginx php php-fpm wget
RUN unlink /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default && mv /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default_old
COPY default_nginx /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default && ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
RUN cd /etc/nginx/ && mkdir ssl && openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key -out /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt -subj "/C=FR/ST=Ile-de-France/L=Paris/O=42/OU=clde-ber/CN=helloworld"
RUN cd /var/www/html/ && wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/5.0.2/phpMyAdmin-5.0.2-english.tar.gz && tar -xvzf phpMyAdmin-5.0.2-english.tar.gz && mv phpMyAdmin-5.0.2-english phpmyadmin && rm phpMyAdmin-5.0.2-english.tar.gz
COPY config_php var/www/html/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
RUN rm /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini
COPY php.ini /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini
##RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install php7.3-mysql
## doute sur démarrage de phpfpm
##RUN cd /var/www/html/ && wget http://repo.mysql.com/mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
##RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.13-1_all.deb
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install php7.3-mysql
RUN cd /var/www/html/ && apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install gnupg lsb-release && wget https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive dpkg -i  mysql-apt-config_0.8.15-1_all.deb && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt -y update && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt -y install mysql-server 
##RUN touch /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock && ln -s /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock /tmp/mysqld.sock && chmod 0755 /var/run/mysqld && chown mysql:root /var/run/mysqld
##RUN rm /etc/mysql/my.cnf
##COPY my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive && mysql_secure_installation --user root --host localhost
##RUN cd /var/www/html/ && apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install gnupg && apt -y update && apt -y install default-mysql-server
RUN cd /var/www/html/ && wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz && tar -xzvf latest.tar.gz && touch .htaccess && chmod 660 .htaccess
RUN cd /var/www/html/wordpress/ && rm wp-config-sample.php
COPY wp-config.php /var/www/html/wordpress/
RUN cp -a /var/www/html/wordpress/. /var/www/html && cd /var/www/html && rm -rf wordpress
RUN cd /var/www/html/ && mkdir wp-content/upgrade
RUN cd /var/www/html/ && chown -R root:www-data /var/www/html && find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \; && chmod g+w /var/www/html/wp-content && chmod -R g+w /var/www/html/wp-content/themes && chmod -R g+w /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
RUN cd /var/www/html/ && wget https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/
RUN cd /var/www/html/ && rm index.html
COPY index.html /var/www/html/
##RUN service wordpress start
COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
##RUN cd /var/run/mysqld && touch mysqld.sock && chmod +x mysqld.sock
##RUN service mysqld start
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
##RUN mysql /run/mysqld -h localhost -u root --skip-password
##RUN service mysqladmin start
##RUN cd /var/run/mysqld && touch mysqld.sock && chmod +x mysqld.sock && chown mysql:mysql -R * && cd /tmp && ln -s /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock mysqld.sock
##RUN echo "CREATE DATABASE wordpress DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;" | mysqladmin -u root --bind-address=localhost status
##RUN echo "GRANT ALL ON wordpress.* TO 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY '';" | mysqladmin -u root --bind-address=localhost status
##RUN echo "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" | mysqladmin -u --bind-address=localhost status
ENTRYPOINT bash docker-entrypoint.sh
```

my docker-entrypoint.sh :

```
service nginx start
nginx -g daemon off;
service php7.3-fpm start
service mysql start
bash
```

Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0):

I made some amendments to the dockerfile and the entrypoint script so it is working now. To run mysqld as root, I used that command :

```
`mysqld --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --user=root -D`
```

so my pid file was no more located in the accessible /tmp/ folder but somewhere else. Then, to connect the database I amended the php.ini file adding those lines :

```
mysqli.default_socket =/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
mysqli.default_host = localhost
mysqli.default_user = root
```

And I had to add this in the wp-config.php file :

```
`define('WP_ALLOW_REPAIR', true);
```

Here is the knew dockerfile :

```
FROM debian:buster

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get upgrade -y && apt-get dist-upgrade -y && apt-get install -y nginx php php-fpm wget
RUN apt-get install -y php7.3-mysql
RUN apt-get -y install apt-utils

RUN unlink /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default && mv /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default_old
COPY default_nginx /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
RUN rm -rf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default && ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
RUN cd /etc/nginx/ && mkdir ssl
RUN openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.key -out \
/etc/nginx/ssl/nginx.crt -subj "/C=FR/ST=Ile-de-France/L=Paris/O=42/OU=clde-ber/CN=helloworld"

RUN cd /var/www/html/ && wget https://files.phpmyadmin.net/phpMyAdmin/5.0.2/phpMyAdmin-5.0.2-english.tar.gz \
&& tar -xvzf phpMyAdmin-5.0.2-english.tar.gz && mv phpMyAdmin-5.0.2-english phpmyadmin && rm phpMyAdmin-5.0.2-english.tar.gz
COPY config_php var/www/html/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
RUN rm /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini
COPY php.ini /etc/php/7.3/fpm/php.ini

RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install libsasl2-2 libaio1 libmecab2 libnuma1 perl && cd /var/lib/ && wget https://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/pool/mysql-8.0/m/mysql-community/mysql-common_8.0.22-1debian10_amd64.deb && \
dpkg -i mysql-common_8.0.22-1debian10_amd64.deb && \ 
wget https://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/pool/mysql-8.0/m/mysql-community/mysql-community-client-plugins_8.0.22-1debian10_amd64.deb && dpkg -i \
mysql-community-client-plugins_8.0.22-1debian10_amd64.deb && \
wget https://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/pool/mysql-8.0/m/mysql-community/libmysqlclient21_8.0.22-1debian10_amd64.deb && dpkg -i libmysqlclient21_8.0.22-1debian10_amd64.deb && \ 
wget https://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/pool/mysql-8.0/m/mysql-community/libmysqlclient-dev_8.0.22-1debian10_amd64.deb \
&& dpkg -i libmysqlclient-dev_8.0.22-1debian10_amd64.deb && \
wget https://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/pool/mysql-8.0/m/mysql-community/mysql-community-client-core_8.0.22-1debian10_amd64.deb && \
dpkg -i mysql-community-client-core_8.0.22-1debian10_amd64.deb && \
wget https://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/pool/mysql-8.0/m/mysql-community/mysql-community-client_8.0.22-1debian10_amd64.deb && \
dpkg -i mysql-community-client_8.0.22-1debian10_amd64.deb && \
wget https://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/pool/mysql-8.0/m/mysql-community/mysql-client_8.0.22-1debian10_amd64.deb \
&& dpkg -i mysql-client_8.0.22-1debian10_amd64.deb && wget https://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/pool/mysql-8.0/m/mysql-community/mysql-community-server-core_8.0.22-1debian10_amd64.deb \
&& dpkg -i mysql-community-server-core_8.0.22-1debian10_amd64.deb && \
wget https://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/pool/mysql-8.0/m/mysql-community/mysql-community-server_8.0.22-1debian10_amd64.deb && \
dpkg -i mysql-community-server_8.0.22-1debian10_amd64.deb && wget https://repo.mysql.com/apt/debian/pool/mysql-8.0/m/mysql-community/mysql-server_8.0.22-1debian10_amd64.deb && \
dpkg -i mysql-server_8.0.22-1debian10_amd64.deb 
RUN apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install mysql-server 

RUN cd /var/www/html/ && wget https://wordpress.org/latest.tar.gz && tar -xzvf latest.tar.gz && touch .htaccess && chmod 660 .htaccess
RUN cd /var/www/html/wordpress/ && rm wp-config-sample.php
COPY wp-config.php /var/www/html/wordpress/
RUN cp -a /var/www/html/wordpress/. /var/www/html && cd /var/www/html && rm -rf wordpress
RUN cd /var/www/html/ && mkdir wp-content/upgrade
RUN cd /var/www/html/ && chown -R root:www-data /var/www/html && find /var/www/html -type d -exec chmod g+s {} \; \
&& chmod g+w /var/www/html/wp-content && chmod -R g+w /var/www/html/wp-content/themes && chmod -R g+w /var/www/html/wp-content/plugins
RUN cd /var/www/html/ && wget https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/
RUN cd /var/www/html/ && rm index.html
COPY index.html /var/www/html/

COPY docker-entrypoint.sh /usr/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
RUN chmod +x /usr/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh
ENTRYPOINT bash docker-entrypoint.sh
```

Here is the knew entrypoint script :

```
mysqld --pid-file=/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.pid --user=root -D
echo "CREATE DATABASE wordpress;" | mysql --port=13306 --host=localhost --user=root
echo "USE wordpress;" | mysql --port=13306 --host=localhost --user=root
echo "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON wordpress.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;" | mysql --port=13306 --host=localhost --user=root
echo "update mysql.user set plugin='mysql_native_password' where user='root';" | mysql --port=13306 --host=localhost --user=root
echo "FLUSH PRIVILEGES;" | mysql --port=13306 --host=localhost --user=root
service nginx start
nginx -g daemon off;
service php7.3-fpm start
bash
```